# Is there any way to automatically gather Sketchflow feedback in regular asp.net instead of using SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, expression-blend, sketchflow

Is there any way to automatically gather Sketchflow feedback in regular asp.net instead of using SharePoint?  I've got a client that likes the Sketchflow experience but dislikes the SharePoint overhead.

Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatically, no. You can export the .feedback files and collect them in some way, but it would require some user action, such as an upload page.